# AWS step function map task parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, step

I have a step function with a map task, as known the map have to work on an array from the ItemsPath, how can i pass the whole input to the lambda and not only the array.

```
{"StartAt": "Find","States": {
"Find": {
  "Type": "Map",
   "MaxConcurrency": 0,
  "InputPath": "$",
  "ItemsPath": "$.Payload.contacts",
  "Iterator": {
     "StartAt": "func",
     "States": {
       "func": {
         "Type": "Task",
         
         "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:....",
         "Parameters": {
        
           
            "Input": {
              "Payload":{
                "contact.$": "$"
              }
            }
          },
         "End": true
       }
     }
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.Input",
  "End": true
}}} ,
```

i want the whole input to be passed in the event parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you use Iterator it will pass the values from ItemsPath as input to Lambda. You can use the Parameters block to transform the input to the lambda and add the whole input. I haven't tried it myself but I'm pretty sure that should do it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html